# Php Exec external python script - Permission Denied

Tags: php, python, shell, exec

I can't run command line script from Exec

```
$exec = exec($command, $output, $return );
```

I have tried passthru,shell_exec,system but obviously this is not the problem.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /root/path/nonce.py
sudo chmo 775 /path/nonce.py
sudo chmo 777 /path/nonce.py
sudo chmo 755 /path/nonce.py
```

didn't helped

```
exec("python -V 2>&1");
```

works

But

```
/usr/bin/python /root/path/nonce.py 

 Array ( [0] => /usr/bin/python: can't open file '/root/path/nonce.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied )
```

dosent

running on nginx and php5-fpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider the permissions for each directory on the path to the Python script. This means:

```
/root
/root/path
/root/path/nonce.py
```

The permissions for the root account are naturally restricted. If you look a root's home directory:

```
$ ls -ld /root
dr-xr-x---. 9 root root 4096 Aug 20 23:50 root
```

You will see that only the `root` user, and users within group `root`, can read or list the contents of `/root`.

It's a bad idea to place your script in root's home. There are more appropriate places such as `/var/www/cgi-bin` assuming that your script is a CGI script. On my system:

```
$ ls -ld /var/www
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4096 Jul 17 17:22 /var/www
$ ls -ld /var/www/cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jul 17 17:22 /var/www/cgi-bin/
```

which can be read and listed by any user. You should install the script in a directory appropriate for nginx.

Answer (score 0):

one of the directories on the path probably lacks `r` permisison for the relevant user - most likely `/root`

can you move the python script to a dir that is world readable?